# ifelse: Assigning a condition from 1 column to another and multiple statements

Tags: r

I've got a data.frame.  I am trying to use values in column 2, 3, 4 to assign a value in col1.  Is this possible?

```
dat<-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5), col2=c(1,2,3,4,"U"), col3=c(1,2,3,"U",5), col4=c("U",2,3,4,5))
dat1=data.frame(col1=ifelse(dat$col2=="U"|dat$col3=="U"|dat$col4=="U", dat$col1=="U", dat$col1))

col1
0
2
3
0
0
```

Why am I getting a 0 where a U should be?

Comment: `ifelse` provides less than intuitive results on a frequent basis. I would recommend using `if{} else{}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't assign within the `ifelse` function.

```
dat1=data.frame(col1=ifelse(dat$col2=="U"|dat$col3=="U"|dat$col4=="U", 
                "U", 
                dat$col1))
dat1
  col1
1    U
2    2
3    3
4    U
5    U
```

Comment: why dont assign with the `ifelse` function? There is no issue in the assignment portion of the OP's question.

Comment: I miss read the question as the code below.  Assigning within an `ifelse` will often not produce the results expected... `dat1=data.frame(col1=ifelse(dat$col2=="U"|dat$col3=="U"|dat$col4=="U", dat$col1<-"U", dat$col1))`

Comment: gotcha, you mean don't assign __inside__ the ifelse statement.  Perhaps edit your answer to reflect that? (right now it sounds like you mean dont assign using ifelse, as in, dont do this:  `x <- ifelse(.)`

Comment: I think the phrase "Don't assign within the `ifelse` function" makes that clear, but feel free to edit.

Comment: Now I'm the one misreading.. :)  I read it your answer as __with__ instead of __within__.  Being that the OP didnt assign within the `ifelse` function...

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to be using this:

```
    dat1 <- data.frame(col1=ifelse(dat$col2=="U"|dat$col3=="U"|dat$col4=="U", "U", dat$col1))
    # I changed the dat$col1=="U"  to just  "U"
```

---

If the question is `"Why am I getting a 0 where a U should be?"` the answer lies in what you have assigned for the if-TRUE portion of your `ifelse(.)` statement.

Your ifelse statement essentially says

```
 if any of columns 2 through 4 are U
 then assign the value of `does column 1 == "U"`   <-- Not sure if this is what you want
 else assign the value of column 1
```

So when your ifelse test evaluates to `TRUE`, what you get returned is the value of `col1=="U"`, but coerced into an integer.  ie: 0 for FALSE, 1 for TRUE

You can also take advantage of T/F getting evaluated to 1/0 to clean up your code:

```
 # using the fact that rowSums(dat[2:4]=="U") will be 0 when "U" is not in any column:
 ifelse(rowSums(dat[2:4]=="U")>0, "U", dat$col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`any()` makes things like this a lot neater

```
head(dat)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    1    1    U
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    4    4    U    4
5    5    U    5    5

apply(dat,1, function(x)any(x=='U'))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
dat[apply(dat,1, function(x)any(x=='U')), 1] <-'U'

dat
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    U    1    1    U
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    U    4    U    4
5    U    U    5    5
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be:

```
dat$col1[as.logical(rowSums(dat[-1]=="U"))] <- "U"


  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    U    1    1    U
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    U    4    U    4
5    U    U    5    5
```